# Replies of tweet from twitter API

Tags: api, twitter

I am trying hard to get any rest service to access the replies of a tweet by the twitter api, but unable to get any result.

Is there is any method to get all replies of a tweet by twitter?

Comment: Maybe this repo can help you: https://github.com/ScrPzz/twitter_replies_scraper

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a method for this.

You would have to pull all recent 'mentions' of the account that sent the original tweet (since the original tweet was sent) and iterate over them looking for a matching `in_reply_to_status_id` property.

You can get mentions via the [mentions timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/mentions_timeline) if it is your account, or via the [search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) otherwise.

Comment: thanks for answer, can you tell me from this how can I get the reply messages.

Comment: I thought I did. The 'mentions' are the messages to the tweeter. The ones with a matching status id are the reply messages.

Comment: there is something special to give in mention_timeline method, as it is not working on my system ,except this all other methods are working

Comment: yup I know that and I am providing the authorization required, but in this case its not working